# refering to the very top of the filesystem

Tags: php, root

my executed file is in

```
/homez.x/user/www/file.php
```

I need a function to only get

```
/homez.x/user/
```

fair enough I can build a function stripping $_SERVER['document_root'] without the last folder, but need to know if is there only one method to achieve this

Comment: `/homez.x/user/` is not the "very top" of the filesystem. `/` is. Does that mean you want to get the path to the user folder?

Answer (score 3):

I'd merely do this:

```
$path = '/home/' . trim(`whoami`);
```

See also: [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Comment: you mean `trim( exec('whoami') );` ?

Comment: @Oddantfr They both do the same thing.

Comment: @Oddantfr: Notice that @seriousdev uses backticks `\``: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: Note that this is not guaranteed to be your home directory on all systems. It's entirely possible for it to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

`/homez.x/user/` isn't the root of the filesystem -- `/` is. Are you looking for the home directory, or just the parent of the document root? (They may not be the same at all.)

The former can be determined using `posix_getpwuid()`. The latter is simply `dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"])`.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, it's a page on my webserver hosting, therefore to refer the root of the filesystem, we need to write /homez.x/user/

Answer (score 0):

By hardcoding a directory structure you lessen the reusability of your code.

So what I would recommend is to **add** this directory-level to your [include_path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) somewhere central - php.ini or by using [set_include_path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php).

[fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) & Co will look for the file in the "included paths" if you provide them with the propper flags.

Comment: great advice, and what the most accurate way to refer the home directory ?

Comment: using an absoulute path to it